# Function made for counting Letters in C doesn't work for the weirdest reasons

Tags: arrays, c, char

I have an assignment to make which has been giving me a headache. I have an array of characters
called "word[]". It's at most 64 chars long, which is why 'i' is counting up to that number.
Now I want to count all the vowels in that array, but for some reason it's telling me that
there is one more vowel than there really is, up to a number of 9 vowels. From 9 vowels onward, it seems to be giving me the correct number of vowels.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int vowelcounter(char word[]) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<64; i++) {
        word[i] = toupper(word[i]);

        if (word[i]=='A' || word[i]=='E' || word[i]=='I' || word[i]=='O' || word[i] == 'U') {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

int main() {
    char word[64];
    scanf(" %s", word);
    printf("Number of vowels is %i\n", vowelcounter(word));
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to have a switch case instead of a if case, but to no avail.

Comment: If the string can be "at most 64" characters long you should check *at most* 64 characters for vowels, not *always exactly 64*. You will evaluate all the "random" content of that arry. Stop at the end of the string

Comment: the array word in main is undefined when declared. you should stop counting when you  reach the 0-character terminating the input

Comment: Use `scanf("%63s", word);` Using unrestricted `%s` is no better than `gets`.

Answer (score 2):

### OP's Problem:

The user may enter a string shorter than the max length, you should iterate through the array until you find the `\0` character. Or calculate it's length with `strlen` and use it as a stopping point.

As is, you haven't initialised the array to 0, and iterate through the whole array regardless of the length of the string. Hence undefined behaviour.

### Buffer Overflow Vulnerability:

The program is vulnerable to a buffer overflow. What's stopping one to enter more than 64 characters at a time? Consider using `fgets` to read a whole line instead, and then parse it accordingly. It reads at most `n - 1` characters and nul-terminates the string.